# Cant style ul list (bootstrap 4, wordpress theme)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm currently facing this annoying issue, that I can't style the ul list. I tried several things; for example using # instead of the . when targetting the "socials" class. Didn't work.

Here's my code:

**html:**

```
<div class="header-information">
    <div class="socials">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'theme_location' =>   'social-menu',
            'container'       =>        'nav',
            'container_class' => 'socials',
            'container_id' => 'socials',
            'link_before' => '<span class="sr-text">',
            'link_after'  => '</span>'
        );

        wp_nav_menu($args);
    ?>
    </div> <!--.socials-->
    <div class="address">
        <p>8000 Zürich, Teststrasse 12 </p>
        <p>Telefonnummer: +410 000 00 00 </p>
    </div>
</div><!--.header-information-->
```

**css:**

```
.socials.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    nav.socials ul {
        float: right;
    }
}

nav.socials ul li a:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 5px;
    content: '\f6af';
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: There's probably an overriding style in the Bootstrap CSS. Try right-clicking on the element and selecting "inspect" (exact wording differs per browser). This will show you the style rules affecting the element. If you've targeted correctly then you will see your styles, but perhaps crossed out. Happy hunting!

Comment: You can also append !important to your styles, for example, try `.socials {background-color:red!important;}` and see what happens.

Comment: its little difficult to predict. Please post your html of 'ul', by the way nav is tag or class?

Comment: Your CSS contains *nav.socials* (media query) and *socials.nav* (at the top). Only one of them can be right.

Comment: even if I only use one of those two (nav/socials), it doesn't work. I also tried `#socials.nav ul`  . Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If your menu structure is this,

```
<div class="header-information">
  <div class="socials">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Then you have an issue with your selector.

This line below,

```
.socials.nav ul{
```

Needs to be this,

```
.socials nav ul {
```

Because `nav` is not a class a but an element.

Hope this helps. Cheers